# 2 x 74LS181 4 bit ALU's cascaded to form 8 bit ALU, Cin problem?

Tags: alu

When trying to add two numbers on my two cascaded 74LS181's I find that the result seems to be right when I tie the carry (Cn) of the least significant one to Vcc, contra my expectation that Cn should be low.

Trying to add zero and zero yields b'00000001'...

I did tie the Cn+4 of the LSB to the Cn of the MSB.

Any thoughts?

Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Active High operands, Cn (carry in) and Cn+4 (carry out) are active *Low* (indicated by the circles on pins 7 and 16 in the logic symbol below).

The least significant ALU's carry input should be set to No Carry, ie. Cn = High.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I've seen that, but I seem not to be able to find how to influence the chip to use Active high / Actie low operands. That's just the piece of the puzzle I need! The Cn+4 of the MSB is low when there is a carry, so I must invert it to show it (i.e. using a LED). Could you explain how this works please (active high/low)?

Comment: When a signal is 'active high' it is positive logic (high = 1, low = 0). When 'active low' it is negative logic (low = 1, high = 0). The 74181 always the works the same whether the operands are positive or negative logic, but the results are _interpreted_ differently. For example logic function code 1 gives A OR B in positive logic, while the _same_ (physical) output becomes A AND B in negative logic. http://www.righto.com/2017/03/inside-vintage-74181-alu-chip-how-it.html

Comment: Bruce, from your answer and the link you specified I could conclude that "Active high" and Active Low" are driven by the M (Mode) pin of the chip. Am I right? - Thanks for that link by the way!

Comment: M switches between logic and arithmetic functions. There is no switch for changing logic polarity. You just select the _function_ (and carry polarity) that produces the correct results for _your_ logic polarity. So eg. logic function 1 is OR _or_ AND, depending on which logic polarity you are using. An OR gate in positive logic (A high OR B high = C high) is an AND gate in negative logic (A low AND B low  = C low) without any physical change to the circuit.

Comment: Okay, clear, thanks for your patience. Now, for arithmetic functions we need the carry to, wel, carry between LSB and MSB. So my LSB Cn+4 is directly connected to my MSB Cn. How will the carry from the LSB be propagated to the MSB chip? I mean, in my 8 bit design, I would like to have both of them to perform the same (logic) function. - by the way, non need for explaining binary on a low level, I've been in ICT for almost four decades... ;-)

Comment: "So my LSB Cn+4 is directly connected to my MSB Cn. How will the carry from the LSB be propagated to the MSB chip?" - through the wire between them! :). Carry out = Low on CN+4  -> low on Cn = carry in.

Comment: :-D LOL... I ment: the carry being high or low has an influence on the functionality of the logic functions, doesn't it? (Am I overthinking stuff?)

Comment: I've decided to just go and build my ALU with my current understanding of the working of this chip. It's for my 8 bit computer that I'm designing and building. I will write the microcode myself, so I can correct some thing in that stage as well... ;-) See this link: http://nerd.gerardwassink.nl/2017/08/20/8-bit-computer-building-up-the-alu/

Comment: Yes, you are overthinking it. Back to my answer:- when using positive logic, Cn (carry in) and Cn+4 (carry out) are active low. Since there is no carry in to the 1st stage, its Cn pin must be pulled high (as you discovered). That's all you need to know! (but _why_ are they active low? That's just how the chip was designed. So why are they active _high_ in negative logic? Because the 181 only has _one_ set of equations, which have to work in both positive _and_ negative logic - result is carry becomes active high in negative logic.). BTW nice website, I have bookmarked it...

Comment: Thanks for the compliment about the website Bruce. I've decided to go with MSB Carry set to High. I will be using Active High operands, it seems more intuitive. Perhaps, later, When I decide I have room on the bus I will make the Carry choose-able from the microcode - as I do the Mode input now.

Comment: "I've decided to go with MSB Carry set to High." - not sure what you mean by this. _Lower_ 4 bit Cn should be set high, and lower Cn+4 connected to higher 4 bit Cn. Higher Cn+4 can go to CPU status register to become the 8 bit carry flag (lower CN+4 too if you want a 'half carry' flag, useful for BCD arithmetic).

Comment: Exactly what I mean Bruce, thanks, keep an eye out for updates on my website. ;-)

Comment: ALU has been built: http://nerd.gerardwassink.nl/2017/08/27/8-bit-computer-alu-complete/

Comment: Continuing... http://nerd.gerardwassink.nl/2017/09/09/8-bit-computer-test-the-output-module/

Comment: You should put a 100nF bypass capacitor across _every_ IC. If my answer is acceptable, please mark it as such.

Comment: New to stack exchange... Now I marked it. ;-)